# Don't understand cause of this TypeError exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygal

Importing the correct modules for this program and then converting `'gdp.json'` into a object that python can use with `json.load(f)`.

```
import json
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS,RotateStyle as RC
from pygal.maps.world import World
from country_codes import get_country_code
#load data into a list
filename = 'gdp.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    gdp_data = json.load(f)
```

Build a dictionary of `gdp_data`:

```
cc_gdps = {}
for gdp_dict  in gdp_data:
    if gdp_dict['Year'] == 2014:
        country_name = gdp_data["Country Name"]
        gdp = int(float(gdp_data['Value']))
        code = get_country_code(country_name)
    if code:
        cc_gdps[code] = gdp
#Group the countries into 3 gdp level
cc_gdps_1,cc_gdps_2,cc_gdps_3 = {},{},{}
for cc,gdp in cc_gdps.items():
    if gdp < 5000000000:
        cc_gdps_1[cc]=round(gdp/1000000000)
    elif gdp < 5000000000:
        cc_gdps_2[cc] = round(gdp/1000000000)
    else:
        cc_gdps_3[cc] = round(gdp/1000000000)
#see how many countries are in each level
print(len(cc_gdps_1),len(cc_gdps_2),len(cc_gdps_3))
wm_style = RC('#336699',base_style=LCS)
wm = World(style = wm_style)
wm.title = 'Global GDP in 2014, by country.'
wm.add('0-5bln',cc_gdps_1)
wm.add('5bln-50bln',cc_gdps_2)
wm.add('>50bln', cc_gdps_3)
wm.render_to_file('global_gdp.svg')
```

Here's the `get_country_code(country_name)` method:

```
from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES
def get_country_code(country_name):
    """Return the pygal 2-digit country code for given country."""
    for code,name in COUNTRIES.items():
        if name == country_name:
            return code
    #if the country wasnt found,return none.
    return None
```

Not sure what it can be…

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Exception has occurred: TypeError
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
  File "C:\Users\kevin\Documents\python_excerise_16-6.py", line 14, in <module>
    country_name = gdp_data["Country Name"]

Comment: `gdp_data` seems to be a list, hence there are only indices (integers) or slices allowed. You may want to check with `print(type(gdp_data))`.

Comment: i did and its list but country_name is only there to be used in get_country_code, so i can use the 2 digit country code. its then turned into a dictionary at code = get_country_code(country_name)
    if code:
        cc_gdps[code] = gdp

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your get_country_code function. Change it like this.

```
def get_country_code(country_name):
    """Return the pygal 2-digit country code for given country."""
    for code,name in COUNTRIES.items():
        if name == country_name:
            return code
        else:
            #if the country wasnt found,return none.
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

This is causing the problem:

```
country_name = gdp_data["Country Name"]
#                            ^^^
```

`gdp_data` is of type *list*, hence it only accepts integers or slices, a string as an index is meaningless to a list.

Comment: so how do i fix it